# node-windows Error 1067: The process terminated unexpetedly

Tags: nodejs, windows

Tengo una API programada en node.js y que hace tiempo instalé como servicio en windows server 2016 con la ayuda del nodo node-windows:

- https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows

El caso es que tras una actualización de los paquetes ahora el servicio no funciona, la aplicación si se ejecuta por consola si funciona pero el servicio no y me da **"Error 1067: The process terminated unexpetedly"**. He probado a borrar y reinstalar el servicio y nada...

En el visor de eventos me aparece esto:

```
Child process [3728 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe  --harmony --max_old_space_size=4096 C:\TsmartApi\node_modules\node-windows\lib\wrapper.js --file C:\TsmartApi\dist\bundle.js --scriptoptions= --log "Tsmart-Api wrapper" --grow 0.25 --wait 1 --maxrestarts 3 --abortonerror n --stopparentfirst undefined] finished with 1
```

y esto:

```
The Tsmart-Api service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 60000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
```

He borrado y reinstalado los paquetes y nada ¿Alguna idea de qué puede estar pasando?
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

He regresado a la versión anterior de node-windows y lo he reinstalado.

- En package.json hay que quitar el símbolo `^` de la versión.
- Reinstalar los paquetes `npm install --secure`